# PHP Fatal error: Class 'URL' not found in /var/www/html/laravel/firstlvproject/config/settings.php

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, jquery-file-upload

I was trying to implement jquery file upload plugin usibg`https://github.com/zimt28/laravel-jquery-file-upload`    and i am getting error on URL::to_route, even for path(). Below is the settings. php code which was given in their doc. I am very new to laravel, any help please

```
 return array(
    //'script_url' => URL::to_route('upload'),
    'upload_dir' => path('public').'bundles/jupload/uploads/files/',
    'upload_url' => URL::base().'/bundles/jupload/uploads/files/',
    'delete_type' => 'POST',
    'image_versions' => array(
        'thumbnail' => array(
            'upload_dir' => path('public').'bundles/jupload/uploads/thumbnails/',
            'upload_url' => URL::base().'/bundles/jupload/uploads/thumbnails/',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: *I am very new to laravel* Okay.. Then why don't you check out https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch and get your basics clear instead of asking the questions directly on SO without you having done any research on your part

Comment: the meta nazis are out today so let me move into a comment

can you add the results of dd(array('script_url' => URL::to_route('upload'),))

Comment: I went through that, but this seems like out of syllabus for me. Also that file upload plugin seems not fitting with l5, can you please help me to get any straight forward fileuploader? I want to implement process bar, cancel, pause, restart etc in it

Comment: Again Jeffrey Way has made a mini project on that.. You can check it out: https://laracasts.com/series/build-project-flyer-with-me .. Check it out, but this series is not free..

Comment: Or even better, if your are self-learner, try out this jQuery plugin: http://www.dropzonejs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should create a model with the name Url or whatever suits best inside your app folder you may also generate a url model by artisan command

```
php artisan make:model URL
```

or you can create one manually e.g

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;

protected $table = 'table_name' // in case your table name is different than plural of model name

class URL extends Model
{

}
```

and then in your controller use this Url model e.g

```
use App\URL;
```

and then you will be able to use

```
$url = new Url;
$url->url = Request::get('url'); //make sure you have used use Illuminate\Http\Request; in starting of your controller
```